# How to convert angular alpha 2 to angular beta?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

This particular [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xTyGA7Klq8Mta2T1yANh?p=preview) is written in alpha.45.

I have already written a successful [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8MzHdvTNAWoD5vJz6juH?p=preview) in angular beta.

I'm trying to combine the two code samples. Generally I would think it it would be rather simple by changing

```
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.45/angular2.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.min.js"></script>
```

There would might be some other changes, but there seems to be a serious issue with HTTP BINDINGS.

On my local I get

> Error: HTTP_BINDINGS is not defined  Error loading

[The angular.io documentation,](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/HTTP_PROVIDERS-let.html) in there live example references alpha.37. I can't seem to get these Http Bindings to load properly.

After some exhaustive google searches I can't seem to find an answer.

Update:

I stopped using Plunker and attempted to follow Eric comments.

Here is my app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';

import {PeopleService} from './peopleService'
import {Person} from './person'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [PeopleService,HTTP_PROVIDERS]

})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello Angular2!</h2>
      <my-person 
        *ngFor="#person of people" 
        [name]="person.name"
        (hello)="saidHello($event)">
      </my-person>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, Person]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public peopleService:PeopleService) {
    peopleService.people
      .subscribe(people => this.people = people);
  }
  saidHello($event){
    alert(`You said hello to ${$event}`)
  }
}
```

and here is my boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

and peopleService.ts

```
//a simple service
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class PeopleService {
  constructor(http:Http) {
    this.people = http.get('src/people.json').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

These are the errors I'm getting in the console:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1/angular2/http"

and

> Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://127.0.0.1/angular2/http    Error loading
>   http://127.0.0.1/angular2/http as "angular2/http" from
>   http://127.0.0.1/app/app.component.js

Comment: It's just the plnkr that is outdated, the code examples are correct. HTTP_BINDINGS was deprecated a lot of alphas ago, you must use HTTP_PROVIDERS, and besides that include the http bundle.

Answer (score 0):

@eric answer was helpful, I just need more details.

I built a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FtW2cj?p=preview) for this issue. The key take away all I wanted to do make a simple http request to get json data from a file.

Hopefully, a full working example will assist someone.

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';
```